# Failed to install Numpy 1.20.2 with Poetry on Python 3.9

Tags: numpy, python-poetry

When I try to install Numpy 1.20.2 module with Python Poetry 1.1.4 package manager (`poetry add numpy`) in a Python 3.9.0 virtual environment, I get:

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I read a few threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237904/numpy-installation-for-python-ver-3-9), but since then it seems the latest Numpy versions are supposed to be able to be built with 3.9 (see [this official Numpy release doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324901/failed-to-install-numpy-in-python-version-3-9)).
Did I miss something?

EDIT: using pip 21.0.1 (latest)

Comment: Which version of `pip` is running in your venv? `poetry run pip --version`

Comment: I'm using pip 21.0.1 (latest). Will edit

Comment: The same issue here with the latest version of everything at the moment. Python 3.10

Comment: Did you find a solution?